# Blocking read and write on anonymous pipe

Tags: windows, linux, unix

I have create a anonymous pipe (using pipe system call in linux and _pipe() in windows).      I wanted to know 
1. Whether the read and write on this pipe are blocking call (i.e if the pipe is full will the write be blocked)?.
2. Is there is any chance of data being overwritten in anonymous pipe?. If yes which is a better alternative to it?

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes -- the pipe blocks when full, although that rarely happens in modern systems with lots of memory.
2. If it happens, its a serious bug.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but here's something I just learned the hard way: if the write end closes unexpectedly, the read end will no longer block. Makes sense, now that I know, but before I understood this, it just looked like the blocking mechanism had failed.